# what's the fundamental differences of variables and symbols?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm rather confused about this.

And what's their relationship(e.g., how one can be used in the context of the other)? Much thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Is [this what you are looking for](https://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/21.5/html/internals_23.html#Symbols-and-Variables) ?

A symbol is basically just an object with four fields:

- a name (a string),
- a value (some Lisp object),
- a function (some Lisp object), and
- a property list (usually a list of alternating keyword/value pairs).

What makes symbols special is that there is usually only one symbol with a given name, and the symbol is referred to by name. This makes a symbol a convenient way of calling up data by name, i.e. of *implementing variables*. (The variable's value is stored in the value slot.)

Similarly, functions are referenced by name, and the definition of the function is stored in a symbol's function slot. This means that there can be a distinct function and variable with the same name.

The property list is used as a more general mechanism of associating additional values with particular names, and once again the namespace is independent of the function and variable namespaces.

---

[phils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324105/phils) points to:

- "[How to make `(make-symbol "foo") (make-symbol "foo")` equal?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39351/how-to-make-make-symbol-foo-make-symbol-foo-equal/39357#39357)"
- "[In elisp, how do I put a function in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943606/6309)"

Symbols in Emacs Lisp are more than just identifiers or names for variables and functions; they are complex objects with several components:

1. **Name**: Every symbol has a name, a string that identifies it. That name is used to refer to the symbol in code.
2. **Value cell**: That is where the symbol's value is stored when it is used as a variable. That value can be any Lisp object.
3. **Function cell**: That holds the definition of a function when the symbol is used to name a function. That allows symbols to have associated executable code.
4. **Property list**: Symbols can have additional metadata or properties attached to them, stored in the property list. That can include various keyword/value pairs for additional information or configuration.

#### Symbol Interning and Creation

Symbols are typically interned, meaning that when the Lisp reader processes your code, it interns every symbol it encounters. That makes sure for any given name, there is a single, unique instance of a symbol within a Lisp environment. Interning allows symbols to be compared efficiently using identity (`eq`) rather than by their names, which is why interning is the norm in Lisp programming.

- **Interned Symbols**: Obtained via `intern`, making sure that for any given name, the same symbol object is returned.
- **Uninterned Symbols**: Created with `make-symbol`, resulting in a new symbol object each time, even if the names are identical. These symbols are not added to the Lisp environment's symbol table, allowing for temporary or private symbols that do not conflict with any global symbol.

#### Symbols as Variables and Functions

A key aspect of symbols in Emacs Lisp is their ability to simultaneously represent variables and functions:

- When a symbol is evaluated, Lisp retrieves its value from the value cell.
- When a symbol is the first element of a list that is evaluated, Lisp executes the code in its function cell.

That dual capability is facilitated by the distinct value and function cells, allowing for the same symbol name to be used both as a variable and as a function without conflict.

#### Practical Usage

- **Assigning Functions**: Using `fset` or similar functions (`defalias`, `defun`), you can assign executable code to the function cell of a symbol.
- **Calling Functions Stored in Variables**: By storing a function (or its name) in a symbol's value cell, you can execute the function using `funcall` or `apply`.

#### Example

```lisp
;; Assigning a function to a symbol's function cell
(fset 'my-function #'example-function)
(my-function) ;; Calls 'example-function'

;; Storing a function in a symbol's value cell and calling it
(setq my-var #'example-function)
(funcall my-var) ;; Calls 'example-function'
```

Comment: Good answer (should have been accepted, I think).  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/39357/454 might also help to enlighten readers who are trying to get to grips with this.  (It's partly about `make-symbol`, but also includes what I think is a useful high-level description of symbols generally.)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943606/324105

Comment: @phils Thank you for your feedback. More than 15 years later, I tried to complement this answer, based on your links. Please let me know if I misinterpreted anything.

Comment: Nice, that all looks fine to me.  I suggest that where you write "Symbols are typically interned" you add something like "when the lisp reader reads your code, it interns every symbol it reads" by way of explaining why interning is the norm.

Comment: @phils Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, a variable is a binding between a symbol and a value. The symbol is the name of the variable. When a bound symbol (ie. a variable name) is evaluated, the variable value is returned,

You can also use symbols which are not variables, ie. names which are not bound to a value. You cannot evaluate an unbound symbol though.

In Lisp-2's a symbol can be bound to both a value and a function at the same time, The context defines if the result of evaluating the symbol is the value or the function.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of symbols is a little bit hard to understand. (Even I'm not sure I got it :) )

You can look at symbols as special variables which behave like constants. There is only one instance in memory, no matter how often you used it.

The benefits are conserving memory and one can see if a value is used in a constant-like manner. (Improves code readability)

You can do *similar* things in C/C++ with `typdef`, in Java with `static final` or in Delphi/Pascal/VB with `const`, but be careful, in those and many other languages "symbol" means something different.