# Emacs Lisp map over a list of function names and call them all with the same arg

Tags: lisp, elisp

I'm having trouble understanding the approach I need to take to fold over a list of functions and invoke them all with a particular argument.

Here is what I as assumed would work. I've tried various variations on it, using `eval` etc. Any pointers?

```
(mapcar (lambda (fn) (fn 'utf-8))
        (list #'set-terminal-coding-system
              #'set-keyboard-coding-system
              #'prefer-coding-system))
```

When I run this I just get "Symbol's function definition is void: fn".

EDIT | Ok, so this works, but it seems odd to need to use `apply` when the above example passes the functions with the `#'function-name` synax.

```
(mapcar (lambda (fn) (apply fn '(utf-8)))
        '(set-terminal-coding-system
          set-keyboard-coding-system
          prefer-coding-system))
```

Comment: Re: oddness, I don't find it any more odd than the dereferencing you have to do if you have the name of a variable as a symbol (or string) and want to access its value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Emacs lisp, symbols have separate value and function slots<sup>1</sup>.

Function arguments are passed in as the *value* of the argument's symbol, but when you evaluate `(fn 'utf-8)` you are using the `fn` symbol's *function* slot, which will not contain what you want (or in this instance, anything at all; hence the error "Symbol's function definition is void: fn").

To call a function held in a variable, you must therefore `funcall` or `apply` (or similar).

See also:

- [In elisp, how do I put a function in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942675/in-elisp-how-do-i-put-a-function-in-a-variable/9943606)
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Calling Functions` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Function Names` <kbd>RET</kbd>

<sup>1</sup> i.e. it is a so-called "lisp-2", as opposed to a "lisp-1" where there is a single name-space for both.

Comment: Thanks. So I knew about the namespace thing, though I assumed that since I was passing them in with the `#'function-name` syntax, the Lisp reader would know they were functions. When do the `#'syntax` come into play? Or is that only a Common Lisp thing? (I'm learning both at the same time).

Comment: Sorry, just found that section in the manual. So `#'name` is just a syntactical variation on `'quoted-name` to be used on functions.

Comment: That's correct, but you probably don't need to use it. `#'...` is short-hand for `(function ...)` which is simply a variant of `'...`/`(quote ...)` that also hints to the byte-compiler that it can compile the quoted form as a function. However in modern Emacs `(lambda ...)` is equivalent to `#'(lambda ...)`, so I believe there are extremely few situations in which you might need to be explicit.

Comment: @d11wtq: It knows that they're functions, as you construct the list. It doesn't know that `fn` is a variable, rather than a function, that's what `apply` or `funcall` do. FWIW, `(funcall fn 'utf-8)` is probably more idiomatic than `(apply fn '(utf-8))` but they do the same thing, so...

Answer (score 1):

For side-effects, [`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list library has function [`-each`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-each-list-fn) and its [anaphoric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro) counterpart `--each`:

```
(-each '(fn1 fn2 fn3) (lambda (x) (funcall x YOUR-ARGUMENT)))
(--each '(fn1 fn2 fn3) (funcall it YOUR-ARGUMENT))
```

If you want to collect results of these functions in a list, use [`-map`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-map-fn-list) instead, with arguments reversed:

```
(-map (lambda (x) (funcall x YOUR-ARGUMENT)) '(fn1 fn2 fn3))
(--map (funcall it YOUR-ARGUMENT) '(fn1 fn2 fn3))
```